# is an element an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you check if an element is an input?

```
if(elm.val() == null){
// is not an input
}
else{
// is an input
}
```

Comment: Define *input* - text, select, radio, button?

Comment: Are you trying to check if an element has a value, or whether an element is actually an input field vs a div or span for example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you know what element you are selecting.

or (if you really do not know) you can do:

```
if(elm.is('input')) {} //assuming elm is a jQuery element
else {}
```

Comment: +1 first to mention `is()`. Agreed it would be better to determine this elsewhere in your code. Furthermore, this simply checks that element is an input, but there are many types of input (e.g. text, radio, password). I'd encourage the OP to be more specific.

Comment: @Jason -- i agree fully. the question is very quirky

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function to determine if an element is an `input` tag:

```
jQuery(elm).is("input");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//jquery    
if( $("#elementid").is("input") ){}
    else
    {}
```